# Trying to create a Singleton Collection initialized from a file with C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, collections, initialization, singleton

I am struggling with something new I am attempting. The app is UWP. Most forms are master/detail. I need a global collection such that all forms will access the same instance of the data. There are no circumstances where the collection could be accessed simultaneously by more than one form or thread.

I have a class (Model) named "Owner".

```
using System;

namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class Owner
    {
        public Int16 Identifier { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public String Image { get; set; }
        public Boolean Active { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

I have created a singleton class named OwnerX. There are two aspects of this class I am struggling with. **First** I need OwnerX to be a collection IEnumerable List of type Owner.  **Second** I need to incorporate the LoadFileAsync method in to the creation process. The form code behind accesses the collection using "OwnersX Owners = OwnersX.Instance();".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using MyApp.Models;
using MyApp.Services;

namespace MyApp.Collections
{
    public sealed class OwnersX
    {
        //Need OwnersX to be an IEnumerable<Owner>

        private OwnersX() { }

        private static OwnersX _instance;

        public static OwnersX Instance()
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new OwnersX();
            }

            return _instance;
        }

        // Need this as part of the instance creation process.

        private static async Task<IEnumerable<Owner>> LoadFileAsync()
        {
            String fileContent = await DataFileServicecs.ReadDataFile("Owners.txt", "Data");

            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(fileContent);

            String header = stringReader.ReadLine();
            String line;

            List<Owner> owners = new List<Owner>();

            while ((line = stringReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] fields = line.Split('\t');

                owners.Add(new Owner
                {
                    Identifier = Int16.Parse(fields[0]),
                    Name = fields[1].Replace("\"", String.Empty),
                    Description = fields[2].Replace("\"", String.Empty),
                    Image = fields[3],
                    Active = Boolean.Parse(fields[4]),
                    Modified = DateTime.Parse(fields[5])
                });
            }

            return owners as IEnumerable<Owner>;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any advice offered.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options

1) You can make LoadFileAsync() be synchronous instead by calling `.Result` on the task retured by `ReadDataFile`. I get the impression from your question that isn't an option.

2) You could make your singleton accessed asynchronously and pass the asynchronous logic upwards

```
public static async Task<OwnersX> Instance()
```

3) You can initialize your singleton using one of the other patterns described here:
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html

Except for the first option, they all basically involve pushing async code upwards. With async code, this is generally what happens and it's not a bad thing. Unless you fully embrace async code by having it be async from top to bottom, you're going to have synchronous code calling asynchronous code somewhere and you just have to find where that point is.

Edit: I didn't answer the first part of your question.

You can have `OwnersX` implement `IEnumerable<Owner>`, and implement `GetEnumerator()`

```
public sealed class OwnersX : IEnumerable<Owner>
{
    private IEnumerable<Owner> owners;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return owners.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So there's a lot of weirdness going on here.  You can't really load a static member asynchronously the way you're trying to do it.  I'm not going to get into the logic of it all but I'll try to answer your question to this and hope it helps.

The solution I would take would be to create an event in the Singleton class and a property that holds the loaded data.  I prefer INotifyPropertyChanged, making it observable, but however is fine.  Then I would make a non-singleton class as a ViewModel that basically borrows the information from the Singleton and listens for changes that the view can bind to.

The idea is that you can instantiate the Singleton and load the data asynchronously.  The ViewModel can be created as often as needed and it first pulls the data from the Singleton as well as listens to the data incase it changes and then updates.  Here's an example of that I mean.

```
public class MySingleton : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private AutoResetEvent ownersResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);
    private List<Owner> owners;
    private static MySingleton instance = new MySingleton();
    private MySingleton() => Initialize();
    public static MySingleton Instance => instance;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    public IEnumerable<Owner> Owners 
    {
        get
        {
            ownersResetEvent.WaitOne();
            var tempOwners = owners?.ToList() ?? Enumerable.Empty<Owner>();
            ownersResetEvent.Set();
            return tempOwners;
        }
        private set
        {
            ownersResetEvent.WaitOne();
            owners = value.ToList();
            ownersResetEvent.Set();
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Owners)));
        }
    }    

    private async void Initialize()
    {
        Owners = await LoadFileAsync();
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Owners));
    }
}
```

Now add a ViewModel.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MyViewModel() => MySingleton.Instance.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
                            {
                                if (e.PropertyName == nameof(MySingleton.Owners))
                                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Owners)));
                            };

    public IEnumerable<Owner> Owners => MySingleton.Instance.Owners;
}
```

Now you can start the singleton and if the data is null no big deal; it will be loading asynchronously anyway and then updated when the data is set.  You can then use the ViewModel as often as needed and it will use the existing data and update when the data updates.  You can then bind to the ViewModel via code or in markup.  You could technically bind to the singleton but you're losing some MVVM power if you're into that. This a simple example; mocked up in my head without a studio; so if there's an error hopefully you still get the idea.

Also, the way I'm locking the loading and getting of data isn't the best way but it was good enough to show you here that the data needs to be synchronized someway if it's loading asynchronously on a singleton.